# Why weren't some of the original Digimon able to evolve into their Ultimate/Mega forms in season 1?

Tags: digimon, digimon-tri

Up until Digimon Tri, only two people from the original Digi-destined were able to evolve their Digimon to their Ultimate/Mega form (and even go beyond that, see [Omegamon](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Omnimon)). All the other characters were stuck with Digimon that could only go up to Perfect/Ultimate form. I get why, it's explained in episode 38 of season 1.

But why has that changed in Digimon Tri? How can Joe and Mimi evolve their Digimon into Ultimate/Mega forms so easily? What made it possible for them in Tri that wasn't possible for them in the original season?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Digivolution](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digivolution) wiki, Agumon and Gabumon didn't quite perform a Mega Digivolution - they performed a *Warp* Digivolution.

> Warp Digivolution is a digivolution process where a Digimon can reach a higher level directly bypassing any intermediate phases

When Tai and Matt were shot with the Angelic Arrows, Agumon and Gabumon wrap digivolved to their Mega forms. During the digivolvution scene, they say

> Agumon/Gabumon **warp** digivolve to WarGreymon/MetalGarurumon

Furthermore, Warp Digivolution and Mega Digivolution are not the same thing. While see Mega forms in season 1, regular Mega Digivolution is actually not seen in Season 2

> Mega Digivolution is a Digivolution method that allows an Ultimate Digimon to digivolve to Mega. **It is initially used by Paildramon to digivolve to Imperialdramon in Digimon Adventure 02.**

In the episode [Determination](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Determination), the digidestined were also shocked to see the fact that Gomamon was able to achieve his Mega Digivolve of Vikemon.

> Joe realizes that his relationship with Gomamon is the more important thing, and so he charges back to the battle. This rebirth of confidence allows Gomamon to achieve his Mega level, Vikemon, **much to everyone's surprise**

Explained in Season 2 a strong bond between two individuals is required to perform DNA Digivolve, and it is possible such bond is able to achieve Mega Digivolution.

> Seeing Joe's resolve, Mimi regains faith in herself as well and helps Togemon her own Mega level in Rosemon.

As we see in the following episodes, there is a continuation of strong, emotional connections between the digimon and digidestined.

[Confession](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Confession)

> Izzy pleads with Tentomon to enter the shield, but Tentomon refuses to do so while his friends are suffering. He digivolves to his Mega form, HerculesKabuterimon

[Loss](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Loss)

> Sora risks her life to protect Biyomon from Machinedramon, digivolving her into her Mega form, Phoenixmon

Answer (score 0):

Warp digivolution and mega digivolution are the same thing bc agumon and gobumon weren't able to achieve mega forms till they got hit with the celestial arrows

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate evolution and Warp evolution are two different evolutions. However they both reach the same outcome of a ultimate level digimon. Ultimate evolution allows a perfect level digimon to evolve to a ultimate level. Warp evolution allows a digimon to jump stright from a child to and ultimate directly advioding the intermidate stages.

the reason in the first series on Taichi And Yamato was hit with hope and light arrows to preform a miracle. fullfilling a prophecy.

***warning Spoilers Ahead***

In Digimon Tri second movie we see kourshiro recieve an anynomous message stating a new prophecy "know the darkness and go beyond" 
as shown the other digidestend faced a darkness of their own allowing there digimon to go beyond the perfect level to ultimate.
mimi- over coming her "darkness" being the faith in herself allowing palmon to reach ultimate 
joe overcoming his "darkness" being his insecurities to fight allows gomamon to reach ultimate 
kourshiro -  overcame his darkness in wanting to protect tentomon but he understands why tentomon refused and that allowed tentomon to reach ultimate
sora - overcame darkness of piyomon hating her after the reboot and wanted to still protect piyomon even if she hated her which allowed piyomon to reach ultimate 
takeru im not completly sure what he overcame maybe it was loosing his partner agian im not completely sure
hikari - overcame the fact that she would have to destroy her friend to save the world allowing her to evolve tailmon to ultimate 
*theory no confirmed*
and even the propehcy could possibly be the reason for omegamon further evolution.
as mieko overcame her darkness of miecoomon being killed which inturn allowed omegamon to shinka furth